# Use flexslider jQuery plugin in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, flexslider

I'm trying to use a flexslider, a jQuery plugin inside a React component.

this is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Testimonial from './testimonial';
import testimonialData from '../API/testimonials.json';
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../flexslider/JS/jquery.flexslider';

class Testimonials extends React.Component {
    divRef;

    componentDidMount() {
        $(this.divRef).flexslider({
            animation: 'slide',
            controlNav: false
        });
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    setRef = (ref) => {
        this.divRef = ref;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container mt-5 pt-2">
                <hr className="testimonials_hr" />
                <h1 className="text-center pb-5">Testimonials</h1>
                <div className="flexslider" ref={this.setRef}>
                    <ul class="slides">
                        {testimonialData.map((element) => <Testimonial id={element.id} {...element} />)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Testimonials;
```

I have installed jQuery and also downloaded jQuery.flexslider file. I've saved it on src folder and i'm importing it to the component to use flexslider().

When I compile it shows on browser:

```
./src/flexslider/JS/jquery.flexslider.js
  Line 25:  'DocumentTouch' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 199:  'MSGesture' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 521:  'MSGesture' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 1252:  'jQuery' is not defined         no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

What do I have to do to use a Flexslider in a React component using a jQuery plugin?

Comment: A much easier solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flex-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flexslider` needs `jQuery` to be in a global scope (e.g.: `window`) to bind its functions to the `jQuery` object.

One possible solution that comes in mind is to require them like any normal script in the `html`-file:

```html
<!-- styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.2/flexslider.min.css" />

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.2/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts can also be loaded from local space if available in source directory -->
```

Another solution I found is to `require` the plugin instead of `import` and define `jQuery` and `$` on the `window` object:

```
import React from "react";
import $ from 'jquery'; // jQuery import

import 'flexslider/flexslider.css'; // The styles if needed

window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
require('flexslider'); // This uses the NPM-package, but it can be replaced by the local file.
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Instead of downloading and pasting manually I downloaded flexslider through terminal. And it worked perfectly with your line of code.